# NextJs Error when connecting to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to connect to my mongodb and fetch some data in server side component in my nextJs app

here is my connection function

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const connectDb = async()=>{
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB)
    console.log("Connected Successfully")
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

export default connectDb
```

**and here is my model**

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

interface IProject {
  id: number,
    name: string,
    skills: string[],
    demoLink: string,
    repoLink: string,
    imgUrl:string,
}

const projectSchema = new Schema<IProject>({
    id: {type:Number},
    name: {type:String,required:[true,"DemoLink is Required"]},
    skills: {type:[],required:[true,"Enter One Skill at least"]},
    demoLink: {type:String, required:[true,"DemoLink is Required"]},
    repoLink: {type:String, required:[true,"RepoLink is Required"]},
    imgUrl:{type:String, required:[true,"Image Url is Required"]},
})

const Project = models.Project || model<IProject>("Project", projectSchema)

export default Project
```

**and finally that is my server component**

```
import Project from "@/models/project"
import connectDb from "../connect"

const Home = async () => {
  await connectDb()
  const project = await Project.find()
  return (

    <div>{project && JSON.stringify(project)}</div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

when I run my app I got this error "MongooseError: Operation `projects.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout"

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create an endpoint in the /api directory,
2. Create a GET request handler
3. Then you'll use the endpoint in your component using a HTTP protocol handler e.g the Fetch API or a library like axios.

There are countless examples on Github to guide you.

Comment: I know what you are talking about, but I want to use all benefits of using server component, so it permits the direct connection to the db, since I can use back end code inside it. Am I right

Comment: And by the way I tried the solution of makin api route handler and I have the sam error, the only solution that worked is when i make an external api and try to fetch data from its endpoint that worked fine with me